# JBoss logger appender with dependency

Tags: jboss, wildfly-10

I'm trying to create a custom logger appender that would be included in Wildfly 
(With jboss cli: `/subsystem=logging/custom-handler=LOG4J_MY:add` and `/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:root-logger-assign-handler(name=LOG4J_MY)`

The problem is that the logger needs to use resteasy, and it seems the `resteasy-jackson2-provider` does not work because I get the following exception when trying to send json:

```
19:07:18,813 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1) javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY004655: Unable to invoke request
19:07:18,814 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.engines.ApacheHttpClient4Engine.invoke(ApacheHttpClient4Engine.java:287)
19:07:18,814 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:436)
19:07:18,815 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation.invoke(ClientInvocation.java:479)
19:07:18,815 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at org.jboss.resteasy.client.jaxrs.internal.ClientInvocation$5.call(ClientInvocation.java:542)
19:07:18,815 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
19:07:18,816 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
19:07:18,816 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
19:07:18,816 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
19:07:18,817 ERROR [stderr] (pool-1-thread-1) Caused by: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: RESTEASY003215: could not find writer for content-type application/json type: my.MyJsonMessage
```

I have defined the appender in `<wildfly>modules/.../module.xml` like this:

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="my.appender"> 
   <resources><resource-root path="my-appender-1.0.1.jar"/></resources>    
   <dependencies>
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" />
        <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
        <module name="org.apache.log4j" />
        <module name="javax.ws.rs.api" />
        <module name="org.jboss.logmanager" />
    </dependencies>
 </module>
```

I am running Wildfly 10.

Comment: I don't recall how it works but try `<module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jackson2-provider" export="true" />`

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins Unfortunately did not work (at least if that change and restarting JBoss is enough).

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't mean `export="true"` I mean `services="export"`. It may need that if it uses a service provider.